# Validating a large CSV file format in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I would like to validate a large (up to millions of rows) CSV file content without reading it twice : once in the validation request file, once when storing the content of the CSV file to the database. What's the best, clean and efficient approach?

Here is what I have so far:

**CreateSymbolRequest.php:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'prices' => [
            'bail',
            'required',
            'file',
            'max:8192',
            new PriceFileExtensionsRule(['csv']),
            new PriceFileHeadersRule,
            new PriceFileDataFormatRule
        ],
        'pair' => 'required|array',
        'timeframe' => 'required|in:1S,1,1H,4H,1D,1W,1M',
        'type' => 'required|in:spot,future',
        'exchange' => 'required|in:FTX,binance',
        'tx_fee' => 'required|numeric',
        'm_fee' => 'required|numeric'
    ];
}

public function persist(): void
{
    // checks if the Symbol already exists in the DB
    if ($this->isSymbolDuplicate()) {
        throw new Exception('Symbol already exists in the database.');
    }

    // Stores the Symbol in the DB
    $this->persistSymbol();
    // Stores the CSV content in the DB
    $this->persistPrices();
}
```

**SymbolsController:**

```
public function store(CreateSymbolRequest $request)
{
    $request->persist();    
}
```

Of course, I could split the basic validation in `CreateSymbolRequest.php` and the more advanced validation in `SymbolsController.php`, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of having a separate Request file with the validation rules in it.

I was also thinking of passing a `$content` variable by reference to the Rule files but I don't think I can return anything from there and that feels very ugly anyway.

Comment: use laravel excel package it will help you to solve your problem no duplicate records  proper data validation and import large data with queue. https://laravel-excel.com/

Comment: Didn't know laravel-excel was including a validation feature, that's good to know thx. Though, after a couple of previous research on the topic, Laravel-excel seems very slow and not memory efficient, which might be a problem with large files.

Comment: with queues it work really fast and you will be notified also when whole data is imported read the documentation it has really good features.

Comment: Alright, you convinced me to give it a try. :)